# How can I create user-inputted less than or greater than (or equal to) variables in R?

Tags: r, subset

I am coding a function that will allow someone to pass 3 datasets into the function, then subset the merged datasets based on greater than/less than/equal to one variable in the datasets.  So something like:

```
myfunc <- function(data1, data2, data3, subsetvariable, gle, criterion){
....
....
}
```

where data1,2,3 are the datasets, subsetvariable is something like age or weight, and criterion is something like 20 years, 145 pounds, etc. The variable gle is greater than/less than/equal to that the user should be able to pass into the function.

Inside the function I will have something like:

```
data <- data[data$age > 30,]
```

It will be easy to simply put in the subsetvariable of age and the criterion variable of 30 into place, but how can I pass the ">" into the function?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: How are you merging the datasets?

Comment: By using the merge function.  However, the subsetvariable in the end will be from the original data1 dataset.

Comment: I have a feeling that `data.table` or `dplyr` will offer more elegant solutions, but you could pass the comparison operator function in using backticks, and then call using `data[gle(data[[subsetvariable]],criterion),]`. Otherwise you could pass as a string and use `match.fun` or `switch`

Comment: What do you have in mind for `dplyr` @James? Is there a `dplyr` internal function that can do that already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the "<" as a character. Just use `?match.fun` to call the proper function.

```
fct <- function(a, b, gle){
  gle <- match.fun(gle)
  gle(a, b)
}
identical(fct(1, 0:3, "<"), 1<0:3)
identical(fct(1, 0:3, ">="), 1>=0:3)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could have the user 2 letter representing greater than, less than or equals like some languages use and use an if else statement.

gt = greater than

ge = greater than or equals

eq = equals

lt = less than

le = less than or equals

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that allows you to pass the full expression the same way you do with `subset`.  No need to niggle with the column, the function, and the value separately:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=letters, b=1:26)
df2 <- data.frame(a=letters, c=LETTERS, age=21:46)

myfunc(df1, df2, age > 43)
```

This returns the two data frames merged, and subset by the expression `age > 43`:

```
   a  b c age
24 x 24 X  44
25 y 25 Y  45
26 z 26 Z  46
```

And here is the source:

```
myfunc <- function(data1, data2, subsetcommand) {
  data <- merge(data1, data2)
  sub.call <- bquote(subset(data, .(substitute(subsetcommand))))
  eval(sub.call)
}
```

The trick is to create a `subset` call on our merged data set, and then `substitute` the user provided command as the second argument to the `subset` call.  This is what the business with the `bquote` does.  `bquote` takes a command, and quotes it so it isn't evaluated by R, but rather stored as a parsed command.  The special part about `bquote` is that it does evaluate the parts of it that are inside `.()`, so the `substitute` can do its work.

Once we have our subset expression with the user expression substituted in, we can just evaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

Though you may be able to rig up something using non-standard evaluation to directly insert the character into the evaluation, the easiest would probably be to use a conditional statement.

Say the user input of for the greater than / lesser than / equal to is called `eq_sym`. Just do something like this:

```
test <- switch(eq_sym, '>' = data$age > 30, '<' = dat$age < 30, '=' = data$age == 30, NA)
if (is.na(test)) {
    stop("must be >, <, or =")
} else {
    data <- data[test,]
}
```